# Cisco 10GB-T module port duplication issue

Tags: 10gbethernet, cisco

I purchased one two port 10GB-T ports network module (C3KX-NM-10GT) for my 3750-X switch stack (4 in the stack). After powering off the entire stack, plugging the module in, re-powered everything. When I run a "sh ip int bri" I see not two but eight 10GB ports. Two for each switch in the stack. Not only that but when I try to plug something into the module it still shows (notconnect) state.

I tried checking the recommend IOS version but the only documentation I could find was on the (C3KX-NM-10G) module, ( http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/OL_6981.pdf ). This shows an IOS version of 12.2(53)SE. I have 12.2(58)SE currently on my stack.

Is this an issue with IOS incompatibility or something else? Does anyone know the recommended version of IOS for this module?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum IOS for the C3KX-NM-10GT module is 15.0(1)SE.

You will need to upgrade the entire stack to 15.0(1)SE and above to get this working.